# Angular 1 $scope and ES6 Promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

Say I have this bit of code:

```
angular.controller('SomeController', function($scope, SomeService) {
    $scope.thing = 'hello';

    const successCallback = (response) => $scope.thing = response;

    SomeService.getTask(someData, successCallback, errorCallback); 
})
```

After SomeService fires the SuccessCallback it will update $scope.thing and everything is fine and dandy.

However, just for funzies if I were to wrap SomeService in a promise like this:

```
angular.controller('SomeController', function($scope, SomeService) {
    $scope.thing = 'hello';

    const successCallback = (response) => $scope.thing = response;

    const promiseWrapper = (someData) => new Promise(
        (resolve, reject) => SomeService.getTask(someData, resolve, reject) );

    promiseWrapper(someData)
        .then( successCallback );
})
```

It would fire the successCallback with the right data but will not update the $scope object.

I'm not really trying to make code like this work, just wondering what's keeping the successCallback in the promise from updating the scope.

And I'm using Angular 1.5 and the Babel ES6 transpiler.

Thanks!

Comment: I just have to ask why you're still binding to scope vs the controller instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `Promise`, which is non-angular Object, you have to update `$scope`props forcefully using:

```
$scope.$apply(() => {
  $scope.thing = response;
});
```

[**JS Fiddle Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/fvWgYRoOh0SWXgbfrUq6?p=preview)

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! 